# docker Vscode Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, ros

I know that this issue has been asked before, but I am still having trouble getting it working.
I am trying to get a ROS project working in Docker and Vscode.
I am getting the following errors. I think it has a to do with the entrypoint terminating but I am not entirely sure how to fix the issue.

Here are my errors:

```bash
Starting code_workspace_1  ... done
[2022-08-04T15:15:04.904Z] Stop (294 ms): Run: docker-compose --project-name code -f /home/nathanielgoldfarb/NAVAIR/code/docker-compose.yml -f /home/nathanielgoldfarb/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1659626104609.yml up -d --no-recreate
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.507Z] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=com.docker.compose.project=code --filter label=com.docker.compose.service=workspace
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.509Z] Stop (50156 ms): Run: docker events --format {{json .}} --filter event=start
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.524Z] Stop (17 ms): Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=com.docker.compose.project=code --filter label=com.docker.compose.service=workspace
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.525Z] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container 4d9f4e7e9f63
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.768Z] Stop (243 ms): Run: docker inspect --type container 4d9f4e7e9f63
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.768Z] Start: Inspecting container
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.768Z] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container 4d9f4e7e9f63cda13b8d893b0e63f2228ff5435112a75d9e6a244e858bd2f96e
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.784Z] Stop (16 ms): Run: docker inspect --type container 4d9f4e7e9f63cda13b8d893b0e63f2228ff5435112a75d9e6a244e858bd2f96e
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.784Z] Stop (16 ms): Inspecting container
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.784Z] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.786Z] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.803Z] Stop (19 ms): Run in container: /bin/sh
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.803Z] Shell server terminated (code: 1, signal: null)
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.803Z] Error response from daemon: Container 4d9f4e7e9f63cda13b8d893b0e63f2228ff5435112a75d9e6a244e858bd2f96e is restarting, wait until the container is running
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.803Z] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.803Z] Stdin closed!
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.804Z] Error: An error occurred setting up the container.
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.804Z]     at DR (/home/nathanielgoldfarb/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:188:2565)
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.804Z]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.804Z]     at async QR (/home/nathanielgoldfarb/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:2177)
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.804Z]     at async cb (/home/nathanielgoldfarb/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:3110)
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.804Z]     at async i_ (/home/nathanielgoldfarb/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:13194)
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.804Z]     at async n_ (/home/nathanielgoldfarb/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:12950)
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.806Z] Stop (51104 ms): Run: /usr/share/code/code /home/nathanielgoldfarb/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /home/nathanielgoldfarb/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --workspace-folder /home/nathanielgoldfarb/NAVAIR/code --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/home/nathanielgoldfarb/NAVAIR/code --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/nathanielgoldfarb/NAVAIR/code/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.806Z] Exit code 1
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.808Z] Command failed: /usr/share/code/code /home/nathanielgoldfarb/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /home/nathanielgoldfarb/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --workspace-folder /home/nathanielgoldfarb/NAVAIR/code --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/home/nathanielgoldfarb/NAVAIR/code --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/nathanielgoldfarb/NAVAIR/code/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-08-04T15:15:54.808Z] Exit code 1
```

Here is my docker-compose file

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  ros:
    driver: bridge

services:

  ros-master:
    image: ros:melodic-ros-core
    command: stdbuf -o L roscore
    tty: true
    networks:
      - ros
    restart: always

  xserver:
    image: devrt/xserver
    command: sleep infinity
    tty: true
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "test -e /tmp/.X11-unix/X0"]
      interval: "1s"
      retries: 20
    restart: always
    networks:
      - ros
  simulator:
    image: devrt/simulator-empty
    tty: true
    environment:
    - DISPLAY=:0
    depends_on:
    - xserver
    restart: always
    networks:
      - ros

  workspace:
    # env_file:
    #   - .env
    tty: true
    networks:
      - ros
    command: sleep infinity
    image: ship
    environment:
      - "ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ros-master:11311"
      # - GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
      # - "ROS_HOSTNAME=warthog"
      - "NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all"
      - "NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all"
      - "QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" 
    volumes:
      - workspace:/catkin_ws
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
    depends_on:
      - xserver
    restart: always
   

volumes:
  workspace:
```

This is my entrypoint file

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e



source "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash"
rospack list
source "/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash"
```